# Core.js and other JS prompt authentication in anonymous site - MOSS

Tags: anonymous-authentication

I've troubleshooting a sympton in our sharepoint farm that is causing me some headaches.

After enabling the hidden feature "ViewFormPagesLockDown" in a anonymous SharePoint site, our site collection is prompting our users when they hit the welcome page.

After take a look in what files has the problem, we found that Core.js , Init.js , NO-IE.js and Search.js were not loaded, giving an unauthorized error. After canceling the prompt window, the page is loaded

We tryed to disable the feature with no luck. The problem persisted. We also tryed to disable and enable the anonymous access again, also, not worked.

Any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out.

When activated, the hidden feature inserts into web.config the following:

```
  <location path="_layouts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

**The fix:**

Keep the tag inserted, then, add the following

```
<location path="_layouts/1046/core.js">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
                <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

<location path="_layouts/1046/search.js">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
                <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

<location path="_layouts/1046/NON_IE.JS">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
                <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

<location path="_layouts/1046/init.js">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
                <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Remember to change de "1046" to your specific language.

Hope it helps you as much as it helped me